# How do I display Label text character-by-character?

Tags: python, animation, widget, kivy, label

I've been trying to code a little text-based adventure game on Kivy. This means, there's going to be lots of text for the users to read, which would be much easier on the eye if not all the text in a Label would be displayed at once, but rather would appear character-by-character in a simple "animation". By the end of this "animation", the entire text would be displayed.

In regular Python, what I want would look something like this:

```
text1 = "Now tell me, what is your astrological sign?\n"
    for character in text1:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

In Kivy, this seems to be much harder since the sleep function just 'sleeps' the entire application. I've searched around and didn't really find anything at all regarding this specific problem. Some others have worked around their need of time.sleep by using the Kivy Clock object, but even here I could only make text display one character at a time (see code below), which is *absolutely not what I want*. I want all the characters to add up and have the entire Label text standing there by the end of this "animation".

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: app.text
    Button:
        text: 'click me'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''


class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty("hello world")
    lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.clicked2, 0.5)

    def clicked2(self, count):
        if len(self.lst) == 0:
            return False
        self.text = "clicked!" + str(self.lst[len(self.lst)-1])
        self.lst.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This is the best I could think of for now, but again, this isn't even close to what I really want.

Does anyone of you have more experience and could help me with this? It would greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work! The code below is exactly what I wanted. I just used string indexes and lists to iterate through it using the Clock.schedule_interval() function.

I added a "valign" and some padding in the kv to make it look nicer. and text_size: self_sice is there to make the text wrap once it spreads over multiple lines.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: app.text
        text_size: self.size
        valign: "middle"
        padding: root.width/20, root.height/20
    Button:
        text: 'click me'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''


class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty("hello world")
    blabla = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    lst = []
    for x in range(len(blabla)+1):
        print(x)
        lst.append(x)
    lst.reverse()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.clicked2, 0.05)

    def clicked2(self,count):
        if len(self.lst) == 0:
            return False
        self.text = str(self.blabla[:self.lst[len(self.lst)-1]])

        self.lst.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you already, answer your question. But, I will show you shorter code, using `scope variable`. To use it declare `nonlocal [var]`

Example:

```
def A(i=0):
  def c():
    nonlocal i; i += 1
  print(i)        #0
  c(); print(i) #1
  c(); print(i) #2
  c(); print(i) #3
A()
```

I use like it in the code below:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App

kv = '''

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: app.text
        text_size: self.size
        valign: "middle"
        padding: root.width/20, root.height/20
    Button:
        text: 'click me'
        on_press: app.clicked()

'''


class MyApp(App):
    text = StringProperty("hello world")
    blabla = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    def build(self): return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def clicked(self, i=0):
      def clicked2():
        nonlocal i; i += 1
        if i > len(self.blabla): return False
        self.text = self.blabla[:i]
      Clock.schedule_interval(lambda count: clicked2(), 0.05)


if __name__ == '__main__': MyApp().run()
```

Comment: That's really cool, thanks for the input! I did try it with a global variable before too, but I've never heard of nonlocal variables until now. Great idea to use nested functions as well! Another idea that didn't come to me. Thank you for your post :)